# How Can I achieve device-to-device automation on Matter Fabric?

Tags: iot, home-automation

As explain over here  https://blog.espressif.com/matter-device-to-device-automations-bdbb32365350,

how we can bind two devices to each other using the binding cluster. And then two devices can talk to each other without the app?
This binding should happen on **Matter Fabric**, and it should not be dependent on the mobile application.

like, once I bind both devices, it should run independently.
for example, I have **two matter enable** devices at my home, one is a thermostat which measures the current room temperature, and if my room temperature goes beyond 35°C (which is quite normal in India ) then my matter fabric or some Automation logic will start Air Conditioning in my home and try to cool-down my room temperature.

Answer (score 0):

Part 3 of [this tutorial](https://grandcentrix.net/en/blog/matter_03/) shows how to bind matter devices. So that one device can directly control another.

```
[{
    "fabricIndex": 1, // Symbolizes the fabric to which the ACL belongs
    "node": 12344321, // Node of the light (all-cluster-app)
    "endpoint": 1, // Endpoint of the on-off-cluster
    "cluster": 6 // on-off-cluster
}]
```